# How to use xarray GroupBy to make grouped boxplots

Tags: python, dataset, boxplot, python-xarray

I have an xarray DataSet that I'm trying to group by 'init_area_rounded'. From there, I wan to create a figure that has the boxplots of each group's 10 hour growth (a variable stored in the DataSet as 'g10').

I want the final figure to have boxplots next to each other with y axis as the 10 hour growth and the x axis as the area (the area they were grouped into).

Sorry if the explanation is rough, it's a bit more complicated than I thought it would be.